# Unable to verify publisher domain for microsoft calendar api

Tags: azure, azure-active-directory, microsoft-graph-api

Unable to verify domain for calendar Api.

The verification file is uploaded to s3, and hosted at the correct Url.

The error message is not related to missing / incorrect headers. It just says internal server error.

Any ideas how this can be debugged?

Tried running the request through postman, output:

```
{
    "odata.error": {
        "code": "Service_InternalServerError",
        "message": {
            "lang": "en",
            "value": "Encountered an internal server error."
        },
        "requestId": "7b674bd0-055c-4db6-90e2-b24b209fea42",
        "date": "2023-06-27T05:08:19"
    }
}
```

The endpoint being called:

```
curl 'https://graph.windows.net/myorganization/applications/f63e480c-2fcf-4089-9423-e46545d6b6b8/verifyPublisherDomain?api-version=2.0' \
  -H 'x-ms-client-session-id: 27fac53b670446b4be1316cbc37faca4' \
  -H 'Accept-Language: en' \
  -H 'Authorization: <redacted>' \
  -H 'client-request-id: fd0979cb-2236-4344-a317-90fa44b70641' \
  -H 'x-ms-effective-locale: en.en-us' \
  -H 'Content-Type: application/json' \
  -H 'Accept: */*' \
  -H 'Referer;' \
  -H 'x-ms-client-request-id: 02ea5cb4-bcd5-43f0-a623-659c5643a022' \
  --data-raw '{"publisherDomain":"<redacted>"}' \
  --compressed
```

Update: as mentioned by @rukmini in the comments, an organisation microsoft account is required for publisher verification.

Update 2: after that, taking these steps verifies the domain: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/active-directory/develop/publisher-verification-overview#requirements

Comment: Could you add more details? What endpoint do you call?

Comment: hi @user2250152 I have added the curl of the endpoint being called on the azure portal.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I created an **Azure AD Application and granted API permissions** like below:

[image]

I generated **access token** using below parameters via Postman:

```json
https://login.microsoftonline.com/TenantID/oauth2/v2.0/token

client_id:ClientID
client_secret:ClientSecret
scope:https://graph.microsoft.com/.default
grant_type:client_credentials
```

[image]

When I decoded the token, the role is displayed:

[image]

**To verify the domain**, make use of below Microsoft Graph query:

```json
POST https://graph.microsoft.com/v1.0/domains/xxx.onmicrosoft.com/verify
```

**As my domain is already verified**, I got the error message:

[image]

The error ***"Service_InternalServerError"*** usually occurs you are making use of `https://graph.windows.net` endpoint as Azure Active Directory Graph is deprecated.

[image]

**Hence**, to resolve the error, check the below:

- Make use of Microsoft Graph API to verify the domain.
- Make sure to grant **`Domain.ReadWrite.All`** Microsoft Graph API permission.
- Check if you are passing the valid query.

**Reference:**

[domain: verify - Microsoft Graph v1.0](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/graph/api/domain-verify?view=graph-rest-1.0&tabs=http)

Comment: I was able to follow all the steps except the last one. The domain I want to verify has the name: xxxxx.com, not xxxxx.onmicrosoft.com. 

I got (if I don't add https in front of the name):
"code": "Authorization_IdentityNotFound",
"message": "The identity of the calling application could not be established."

If I do I get:
"code": "BadRequest"
"message": "Resource not found for the segment 'www.xxxxx.com'."

Comment: Check this https://github.com/toddkitta/azure-content/blob/master/articles/active-directory/active-directory-add-domain-add-verify-general.md

Comment: Checked the docs, but in custom domains -> add, the option is greyed out for me. Please note my license is Azure AD Free. Also, this application is not hosted on azure, it just has to be verified by microsoft to be able to use the calendar api properly.

Comment: I saw this doc, https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/active-directory/develop/publisher-verification-overview#requirements

It says that one has to use their work or school account to get verified by microsoft. So is there no way to do publisher verification as an individual?

Comment: Our organisation is currently not using the microsoft suite or azure cloud, so I don't have a "organisation" microsoft account.

Comment: Yes, it needs "organization" Microsoft account to publish domain.